# Losing a Webapp's Stored Data Completely on iOS15 and iOS16

Tags: ios, local-storage, wkwebview, indexeddb

Our app is a hybrid app, using WKWebView.We seem to lose stored data on both localStorage and IndexedDB on iOS devices.About 100 of 25000 unique users are affected and it seems that some devices lose data frequently  and for most users it haven't happened even once. The affected users had a lot of available memory, usually about 22GB of 32GB.
I tentatively conclude that the IOS deletes WKWebView-related storage after killing the app thread, but I'm not sure of the reason.

Does anyone else experience these issues? Has Apple changed their "clear web app's cache folder" strategy in recent iOS releases or is there a known bug at some level Dexie/IndexedDB/Safari/iOS?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Try a google search for Apple Intelligent Tracking Protection. Apple has undermined browsers on iOS in the name of "privacy". It is a political answer. You will not find much help online because of this, and that is by design.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for your sharing. I have already replaced localStorage and indexedDB with SQLite.